# Lock create/update/delete requests per user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, locking

I have a payment system written in Asp.Net Core & Entity Framework & SQL Server.
I have to deal with many security situations where I need to prevent 2 or more actions performed by the user at the same time. For example:

Every time a payment transaction happens

1. Check user balance and block if there is not enough credit.
2. Perform the payment and reduce the user balance.

Now if a user fires 2 or more request to create payments, some of the requests will past the available credit validation.
Since I have many scenarios similar to this one I thought about a general solution that can solve all of them. I thought about adding a middleware which will check each request and to the following:

1. If the request is a GET request it will pass - this will enable concurrency GET requests.
2. If the request is a POST/PUT/DELETE request it will check if there is already an existing POST/PUT/DELETE for this specific user (assuming the user is logged in). If there is, a response of bad request will return to the client.

In order to do this in the correct way and support more than 1 server, I understand that I need to do this in the database level. I know that I can lock a specific row in Oracle and thinking about locking the user row on the beginning of each UPDATE/CREAT/DELETE and release it in the end. What is the best approach to do this with EF? Is there a better solution?

I'm using the UnitOfWork pattern which each request has its own scope.

Comment: This is better handled via a state machine on your order. Start your order as "submitted", and then once payment has actually been received, you can move it to "paid". If there's not enough funds, you can move it to a "declined" state, and then notify the user.

Comment: Hi Chirs Pratt, thank you for your help. As I mentioned in the down comment:
As for today, there can not be more 2 UPDATE/DELETE/PUT concurrency requests from the user unless there is a bug in my site or the user did it illegally. Using a message queue and return 200 will force me to do a lot of refactoring in the client-side since I'm using the result in the client after a creation. Also, handling error might be much harder in the client, since I will not have an immediate response from the server.

Comment: That's kind of the point. You're trying to make something synchronously which is inherently asynchronous. Things like obtaining funding, whether that actually be through a payment provider or simply internally deducting from an account doesn't happen immediately, and multiple attempts can be made out of band. There's no true reliable way to gate it, unless you literally just allow one person at a time to use your site. As such, a state machine is the only real option.

Comment: It also avoids having to do things like handle errors at the client. The order gets submitted, and the user is simply notified at a later point when the payment is applied or rejected. There's a reason that virtually every ordering system on the planet works this way (state machine)

Comment: Chris thank you very much. would you have given me a different answer for a different but yet related scenario? Let's assume we have a service that enables each user to send up to 5 greeting cards every day. When the user sends a new request I need to check how many cards he sent today. So I need some lock to make sure there is no race condition, but I do not want to block other requests by other users.
This example is a little different because the user balance is time-related and can not be changed by other users in the system,
 if I understand it correctly there can't be a deadlock.

Comment: Time-based changes nothing, the time is the time of the submittal, so you would use that to determine whether there's still cards available, not when it's actually processed. However, in that situation, you could simply to a count on the table. Nothing needs to actually be updated, and the DB will natively lock during the count.

Answer (score 4):

I'd vote against using row locks as a mechanism of request synchronization:

- even though Oracle is known for not escalating row locks, there are transaction-level and other optimizations that may decide to escalate, which can lead to reduced scalability and deadlocks.
- if two users want to transfer money to each other, there's a chance they'll be deadlocked. (If you don't have such a feature right now, you may have it in the future, so better create an architecture that wouldn't be invalidated that easily).

Now, a system that returns "bad request" just because another request from the same user happens to take a longer time, is of course a fail-safe system, but its reliability (a metric of running without failures) suffers. I'd expect any payment system in the world to be both fail-safe and reliable.

> Is there a better solution?

An architecture based on [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and [shared-nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared-nothing_architecture) approaches:

- ASP.NET server ("web tier"):

  - directly performs read (GET) operations, as it does now
  - submits write (POST/PUT/DELETE) operations into a queue, and returns HTTP 200 immediately.
- Application tier: a cluster of (micro)services that fetch and perform the write requests, in a shared-nothing manner:

  - **at any moment, requests from any particular user are processed by at most one thread in the whole system (across all processes and machines)**.
  - the shared-nothing approach ensures that you never have to concurrently process requests from the same user.

#### Implementing shared-nothing

The shared-nothing architecture can be implemented by partitioning (AKA sharding). For example:

- you have N processing threads running (inside some processes) on a cluster of M machines
- each machine is assigned a unique role to run a specific range of threads out of these N
- each request from a user is always dispatched to the same specific thread by calculating: `thread_index = HASH(User) % N`, or if User ID is an integer: `thread_index = USER_ID % N`.
- how the dispatched requests are passed to the processing threads depends on the chosen queue. For example, web tier can submit requests to N different topics, or it can directly push the requests to a distributed actor (see [Akka.Net](https://getakka.net/)), or you can just use database table as a queue, and make each thread fetch the requests that belong to it.

In addition, you'll need an orchestrator to ensure that each of the M machines is up and running. If a machine goes down, the orchestrator spins up another machine with the same role. For example, if you dockerize your services, you can use [Kubernetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes) with [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

Comment: Hi felix-b, first of all, thank you for the time and effort you put in your answer - I really appreciate it. As for today, there can not be more 2 UPDATE/DELETE/PUT concurrency requests from the user unless there is a bug in my site or the user did it illegally. Using a message queue and return 200 will force me to do a lot of refactoring in the client-side since I'm using the result in the client after a creation. Also, handling error might be much harder in the client, since I will not have an immediate response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled recently accross the same thoughts. For some reason some of my users are able to post a formular twice, which results in duplicated data.

Even if this is a old question, i hope it will helps someone.

Like you mentioned, one approach is to use the database for the locking of properties but like you, i couldn't find a solid implementation. I'm also assuming that you have a monolithic application as @felix-b mentioned a very good solution.

I gone the way of making the threads that normally would run concurrent to run in sequence. This solution may suffer some disadvantages, but i could not find any. Please let me know your thoughts.

So i solved it with a dictonary containing the UserId and a SemaphoreSlim.

Then i simply marked the controllers with a ActionFilter and throttle the execution of a controller method per user.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AtomicOperationPerUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<AtomicOperationPerUserAttribute> _logger;
        private readonly IConcurrencyService _concurrencyService;

        public AtomicOperationPerUserAttribute(ILogger<AtomicOperationPerUserAttribute> logger, IConcurrencyService concurrencyService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _concurrencyService = concurrencyService;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            int userId = YourWayToGetTheUserId; //mine was with context.HttpContext.AppSpecificExtensionMethod()

            _logger.LogInformation($"User {userId} claims sempaphore with RequestId {context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier}");

            var semaphore = _concurrencyService.SemaphorePerUser(userId);

            semaphore.Wait();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            int userId = YourWayToGetTheUserId; //mine was with context.HttpContext.AppSpecificExtensionMethod()

            var semaphore = _concurrencyService.SemaphorePerUser(userId);

            _logger.LogInformation($"User {userId} releases sempaphore with RequestId {context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier}");
            
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
```

The "ConcurrentService" is a Singleton registered in the Startup.cs.

```
public interface IConcurrencyService
{
    SemaphoreSlim SemaphorePerUser(int userId);
}

public class ConcurrencyService : IConcurrencyService
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<int, SemaphoreSlim> Semaphors = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, SemaphoreSlim>();

    public SemaphoreSlim SemaphorePerUser(int userId)
    {
        return Semaphors.GetOrAdd(userId, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
    }
}
```

Since in my case i needed dependencies in the ActionFilter is mark a controller action with `[ServiceFilter(typeof(AtomicOperationPerUserAttribute))]`

accordingly i registered the "services" in the `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<AtomicOperationPerUserAttribute>();
services.AddSingleton<IConcurrencyService, ConcurrencyService>();
```